# Why does gedit run python code?

Tags: python, gedit

I just stumbled upon a *really* weird problem.

normally I use gedit to write my python (2.7) scripts.
I have a folder, it contains a script called copy.py
When I now type gedit copy.py, it acutally runs the script, creates a copy.pyc file, and then opens it up to let me edit it. Why?
Apparently, the plugin codecomment from the gedit-plugin package (Linux Mint 17.2) has something to do with, because this behaviour is gone when I deactive it.
It even executes this script when I just type gedit into the terminal.

I also get a couple of error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/gedit-2/plugins/codecomment.py", line 269, in activate
    window.set_data(self.DATA_TAG, CodeCommentWindowHelper(self, window))
  File "/usr/lib/gedit-2/plugins/codecomment.py", line 217, in __init__
    self._insert_menu()
  File "/usr/lib/gedit-2/plugins/codecomment.py", line 230, in _insert_menu
    _("Co_mment Code"),
  File "/usr/lib/gedit-2/plugins/codecomment.py", line 32, in <lambda>
    _ = lambda s: gettext.dgettext(GETTEXT_PACKAGE, s);
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 545, in dgettext
    codeset=_localecodesets.get(domain))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 497, in translation
    t = copy.copy(t)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'copy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/gedit-2/plugins/codecomment.py", line 276, in update_ui
    window.get_data(self.DATA_TAG).update_ui()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update_ui'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/gedit-2/plugins/codecomment.py", line 276, in update_ui
    window.get_data(self.DATA_TAG).update_ui()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update_ui'
```

And after closing the window, it also says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/gedit-2/plugins/codecomment.py", line 276, in update_ui
    window.get_data(self.DATA_TAG).update_ui()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update_ui'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/gedit-2/plugins/codecomment.py", line 272, in deactivate
    window.get_data(self.DATA_TAG).deactivate()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'deactivate'
```

I do not have the python console plugin activated.

Apparently it behaves totaly normal in other folders.

Has anybody seen something like this?

Comment: What is your gedit version?

Comment: What version of `gedit`? This looks like a bug (basically, including the current directory in the Python search path so that `import copy` will find `copy.py` in your local directory rather than the actual system module).  I'm not able to reproduce this with gedit-3.18.3 (and the codecomment plugin).

Comment: My gedit version is 2.30.4

Comment: There is no import copy command in my script. It only import os and then starts a couple of os.system('cp -r ....') commands. I also cannot reproduce this on another machine using the same gedit version and the plugin, only in this folder, AND in copies of the folder and the script. Maybe I should also mention that I have a couple of screen running ... maybe that somehow affects it?

Comment: It looks like this has to do with the codecomment plugin. Maybe try to disable it? Anyway it's a bug that should be reported.

Comment: strange ... I opened a new terminal and tried it there, now gedit behaves as it should, it does start my script.

Comment: Did you set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include the current directory? That would cause the error because it causes the plugin to import `copy` from the wrong place.

Comment: No, I did not have the folder in PYTHONPATH. But I also do not use import copy in the script.

Comment: I think is this bug http://bugs.python.org/issue6895 
Can you reconfigure locale settings and put your locale encoding? (in Mint is the same way as debian dpkg-reconfigure locales as root)

Comment: I dont see any resemblence to this issue ...

Comment: @Pythoneer https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/368391